# Dimension of subspace consisting of commuting matrices with a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $4 \times 4$ matrix with the characteristic polynomial $(x-1)^{4}$ and $A$ is not identity.
 What can be the maximum possible dimension of the subspace consisting of the matrices commuting with $A$?

Comment: I was just able to see that it should be greater than 4 and for maximum possible dimension the minimal polynomial should be $(x-1)^{2}$ (I am not sure but I think that should be the case)

Comment: There's a (small) finite number of Jordan forms to check.